# Issue with Discord.js voice player

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to set up a simple music bot on discord.js for my DnD group, and I can get it to pull up commands, join the server, and search for YouTube videos, but I cannot get it to play on the voice channel, giving me a *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'once'). I'm just starting code and this has completely stumped me.

Here's the play code and the `index.js` file. There may be some glaring problems I'm missing, and any help would be appreciated!

Play code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const {
  createAudioPlayer,
  createAudioResource,
  AudioPlayer,
  VoiceConnection,
  joinVoiceChannel
} = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { VoiceChannel } = require('discord.js');

const player = createAudioPlayer();

const resource = createAudioResource('ytdl');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Plays video',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('I cannot enter the tavern!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('I cannot reach you!');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('I cannot hear you!');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to tell me the song!');
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
          const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
          return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
        if(video){
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
           player.play ( stream, { seek: 0, volume: .5 })
          ;
          connection.subscribe(player);
         await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
         message.channel.send(`No video results found`);
        }
    }
    
}
```

`index.js`:

```
console.clear();

const fs = require('fs');

const { Client, Collection, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [32767] });

client.commands = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('The Nymph awakens.');
});


client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if(command === "ping") {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);} else if (command === "play") {
            client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
          } else if (command === "leave") {
            client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
          }
        
         
         if(message.content === '!join') {
            const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
           if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('I cannot enter the tavern!');
           joinVoiceChannel({
             channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
             guildId: message.guild.id,
              adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
                  })
              }
          
        
        
        
          if(command === "hello") {
            message.channel.send('You wish to speak?');
          } else if (command == 'goodbye') {
            message.channel.send("See you on the morrow.");
          } else if (command == 'hey') {
            message.channel.send("I wish not for hay."); 
          } else if (command == 'hi') {
            message.channel.send("No, I am low to the ground.");
          } else if (command == 'bye') {
            message.channel.send("Farewell.");
          } else if (command == 'Status') {
            message.channel.send("I fare well.");
          } else if (command == 'dnd time') {
            message.channel.send("I am oft unawares.");
          } else if (command == 'wake') {
            message.channel.send("Why do you rouse me?");
          } else if (command == 'intro') {
            message.channel.send("I am a nymph named Aria. I help adventurers in their quest to be immersed in their work.");
          }
      

    if (!command) return;

    
    
});

client.login(token);
```

**Edit: I believe the error is coming from this particular line of code, and this is the error that occurs.**

```
const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
        if(video){
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
           player.play ( stream, { seek: 0, volume: .5 })
          ;
          connection.subscribe(player);
         await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
         message.channel.send(`No video results found`);
```

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'once')
at AudioPlayer.play (C:\Users\"my user name"\Documents\DungeonNymph\node_modules@discordjs\voice\dist\audio\AudioPlayer.js:221:29)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\"my user name"\Documents\DungeonNymph\Commands\play.js:38:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and include a stack trace of the error/details about where the error is occurring? If the error is occurring directly in the code you posted, the only location would be at `client.once('ready', () => {`, which shouldn’t throw that error as `client` is already defined with `const client = new Client(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help with the formatting, and I added the stack trace to help find this broken part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`AudioPlayer#play`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html#play) accepts an [`AudioResource`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioresource.html), not a stream.

Use [`createAudioResource`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#createaudioresource) to create an audio resource with the ytdl stream:

```js
const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inlineVolume: true });
resource.volume.setVolume(0.5);
player.play(resource);
```

If `inlineVolume` is set to `true` (default `false`), `resource.volume` will be a [prism-media `VolumeTransformer`](https://amishshah.github.io/prism-media/?api#new-core.VolumeTransformer), which you can use to set the volume of the stream.

The documentation for the options for `createAudioResource` and the options aren't showing on the documentation website ([#211](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/pull/211)), but you can find the relevant documentation comments in the source:

- [`createAudioResource`](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/blob/v0.6.0/src/audio/AudioResource.ts#L206-L220)
- [`CreateAudioResourceOptions`](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/blob/v0.6.0/src/audio/AudioResource.ts#L7-L36)

I recommend taking a look at the [music bot example](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/tree/f1869a9af5a44ec9a4f52c2dd282352b1521427d/examples/music-bot) in the @discordjs/voice repository to see how to use the library.